# is it correct to say "I really like to meditate on you"?

Tags: word-choice

Ok, let say I am loving a girl. When I close my eys I think about her over and over again without boring.

So, is it ok to say that "I really like to meditate on you/her"?

Comment: It sounds a little like you'd like to sit on her and meditate. I know your intent, but if English isn't your native language, why argue with the answers? Tell her you'd like to meditate on her, if that's what you want to say, and if she gets this "omgthisisn'treallyhappeningtomeisit?" look on her face, then you'll know for sure that we were right. If she gets a "<3" look on her face, you are correct.

Answer (score 2):

It's an unidiomatic word choice. Depending on the personality of the girl in question, that might kill any intended romance.

A more idiomatic, romantic phrasing is **"I love to daydream about you."** 'Dreaming' has more romantic connotations than meditation. While awake, the activity is called 'daydreaming.' '**Fantasizing**' is another option, but has slight sexual connotations.

**"I can't stop thinking about you"** is also a common term for a similar situation. It's well-known and generally well-received.

Comment: it is more than thinking or daydream. It is meditation which is to think over over and over again until you feel like "you're inside her" or "you and her is one"

Comment: "I get lost in deep thoughts of you." "I see us as one." Meditation feels cold due to its ties to religion, philosophy, and strict discipline. If you're going for a single phrase, I recommend one of those I've submitted. If you really want to capture your feelings, though, you may be better served to engage in a longer conversation with the object of your affections.

Comment: That would sound really creepy to most young ladies I know. I would strongly recommend against saying anything like that to most girls.

Comment: if you love Eastern Philosophy, then you would like to mediate on somebody. Meditation is very high level of thinking. You will be thinking beyond the limit. "get lost in deep thoughts" does not 100% convey the idea & does not have the implication as meditation.

Comment: If you love “Eastern philosophy” (which one? There are dozens, and they're quite different from one another), you'll know that in most of them, you don't meditate _on_ anything at all, least of all people. Meditation is a state of mind, attempting to clear and analyse the conscious mind by stepping outside it. That does not apply to thinking about someone you like. _Meditate on someone_ means to pin them to the floor, sit on top of them, and then meditate.

Comment: Since _meditate_ is often used with connotations of religious worship or reflection, saying that you will meditate on a girl will, if she doesn't interpret it with the "literally meditating on top of her" meaning, at the very least make her believe that your adoration for her approaches cultish levels, which may very well frighten her off.

Comment: @Janus, look at "Tantric sex" of Acient Indian. In Tantric sex, a male & a female look at each other for a very long period of time to a level they feel their souls melted into each other before actually having sex.